# Programmatical click on <a>-tag not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, click

I have a problem with the `click()`-function from jquery. I create a `<a>`-element with `document.createElement('a')` and want call the `click()`-function about this element. About this element, I want to create an Excel-file and save this at the desktop.

My code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#test', function(event) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'test.xls';
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;utf-8,test';
    link.click();
});
```

This function work under chrome, but not under Firefox.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/0hnuw6b4/1/)

Does anyone have any idea why that does not work?

Comment: This works for me on Firefox 72.0.2 on Ubuntu. Can anyone please provide link to some resource confirming the change?

Answer (score 107):

In Firefox, you can explicitly add the created element to the DOM and it will work:

```
$('body').on('click', '#test', function(event) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    // Add the element to the DOM
    link.setAttribute("type", "hidden"); // make it hidden if needed
    link.download = 'test.xls';
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;utf-8,test';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hnuw6b4/17/)

Comment: @WhistleWhite that's great! Perhaps you could be so kind as to "accept" my answer by clicking the check mark. :)

Comment: @lurker var anchor=document.createElement('a') will gives var anchor=`<a>` in firefox and in chrome var anchor='<a></a>' . because there is no closing brackets in firefox thats why you can't able to perform click method ???

Comment: Is there any other way to do this in Firefox? (I don't want to append the link to the body)

Comment: Setting type to hidden doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: This works for Firefox and Chrome but not Safari as of 1 June 2017

Comment: @Blackstone4 I don't have Safari on my machine. My answer does say, "In Firefox...". Gotta love HTML/browser "standards"...

Comment: @lurker yep.... [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) is not supported on Safari

Answer (score 99):

You don't have to add the element to the DOM, even in FireFox.
Replace the .click() method with the following code:

```
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(`click`, {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'test.xls';
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;utf-8,test';
    link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Download</button>
```

Comment: this is the more elegant solution in 2018. I tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: Does the second parameter really need? It works on mine with just `link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));` so I'll stick with it, or will there be something that I will miss?

Comment: Easily the most beautiful solution to my problem. Concise and works on every browser I tested so far. Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera

Comment: This is very nice, but `new MouseEvent` is not supported by Internet Explorer. There is a Polyfill needed (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill)

Comment: @ak.leimrey Does this really work in **Edge**? It seems to just dump the data URI to the console :-?

Comment: @Álvaro González It indeed does work. It's what I used in a component of mine and so far the customer had no issue in downloading it, but I realized that it might have to do with polyfills. It's been a while since I used that solution.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Sorry, I just rechecked my project; There was indeed an issue with the implementation. I don't know what was the reason, I had to slightly change the way I'm using this. I think there was an issue with IE 11.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for adding a snippet of code. I have to say that I'm not a big fan of libraries like jQuery.

Comment: These option, which are provided in example are redundant. They are not listed in mdn web [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent)

Answer (score 7):

Add the element to the DOM before triggering the click:

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

This worked for me in all the major browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for creating the element. It will work on both the browsers

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function (event) {
    var link = $("<a/>", {
        "download": "test.xls",
        "href": "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;utf-8,test"
    });
    $("#test").append(link);
    link.get(0).click();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0hnuw6b4/7/)

Comment: It's an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
  var fileUrl=document.createElement('a');
      fileUrl.href=response.request.responseURL;
      document.body.appendChild(fileUrl);
      fileUrl.click();
```

add document body, thats working

Comment: I have issue with latest FireFox that it is failing because of Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:https://FQDN/b234e319-3404-452c-907c-15d178010fc4 (“frame-src”)
How to fix it? On Server it is using Tomcat