# typescript anchor tag click event in firefox not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating anchor tag in typescirpt file.on click of this button anchor tag gets created.It works in chrome & IE but not working in firefox.

```
btnGuest(){
var redirect = <HTMLAnchorElement>document.createElement("a");
      redirect.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/';      
      redirect.target = '_blank';
      redirect.click();
}

<button (click)="btnGuest()"></button>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `window.location` ?

Comment: Not working? What is happening? Are you getting any errors? Any warnings in console? Please explain **not working**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatical click on <a>-tag not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225904/programmatical-click-on-a-tag-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Don't you have to include the link created in the DOM first??

Comment: no i can't use window.location if user has blocked popup it will not open in new tab.

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: What does the debug say? Does the element properly get created in FF with the attributes?

Comment: yes it get created.when i log to the console it show me like this .<a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank">. try console.log(redirect)

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/968992 finally i got the answer after creating element we need to append the element to the document body.here is the code.                                                            var redirect = <HTMLAnchorElement>document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(redirect);
      redirect.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/';      
      redirect.target = '_blank';
      redirect.click();

Answer (score 1):

finally i got the answer after creating element we need to append the element to the document body.here is the code.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/968992

```
var redirect = <HTMLAnchorElement>document.createElement("a"); 
document.body.appendChild(redirect); //required in FF, optional for Chrome
redirect.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/';
redirect.target = '_blank'; 
redirect.click();
```