# revokeObjectURL not work in mozilla firefox and Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, ajax

However, we do not have to update the page. This code works perfectly in google chrome, but in mozilla firefox and Microsoft Edge simply does not do anything, the download does not start or show any error in the console.
Am I doing something wrong or is it an incompatibility problem?

Ajax:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"../../views/ajax.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:dato,
                        cache:false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData:false,
                        xhrFields: {
                            responseType: 'blob'
                        },
                        beforeSend: function() {
                          $("#loading").removeClass('d-none');
                        },
                        success: function(regresos){
                            alert(regresos);
                            $("#loading").addClass('d-none');
                            descargar(regresos, nombre);
                        }
                    });
```

The function that starts the download:

```
 function descargar(blob, nombre){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob([ blob ], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
        );

    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'perfil_' + nombre + '.pdf';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatical click on <a>-tag not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225904/programmatical-click-on-a-tag-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: But beware, revoking the URL right after calling click might also make your download to fail, while the click event will get dispatched synchronously, the fetching algo of download is suposed to be done "in parallel", i.e it could be delayed to after current js-execution in single-thread environment, and would then fail since the blobURL would not point anywhere anymore. Better add a small delay before calling `revokeObjectURL`.

Comment: @Kaiido How do I do it?

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout