# Change Blob Filename

Tags: javascript, html

I am using code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500465/10241621 that downloads file from link. It does work but I do not know how to make a custom filename.

```js
function forceDownload(blob, filename) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = blob;
  // For Firefox https://stackoverflow.com/a/32226068
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}

// Current blob size limit is around 500MB for browsers
function downloadResource(url, filename) {
  if (!filename) filename = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
  fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Origin': location.origin
      }),
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      forceDownload(blobUrl, filename);
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
}

downloadResource('https://giant.gfycat.com/RemoteBlandBlackrussianterrier.webm');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new file name is the second parameter to the function `downloadResource(url, filename)`

```js
function forceDownload(blob, filename) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = blob;
  // For Firefox https://stackoverflow.com/a/32226068
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}

// Current blob size limit is around 500MB for browsers
function downloadResource(url, filename) {
  if (!filename) filename = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
  fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Origin': location.origin
      }),
      mode: 'cors'
    })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      forceDownload(blobUrl, filename);
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
}

downloadResource('https://giant.gfycat.com/RemoteBlandBlackrussianterrier.webm', 'NewName');
```