# Unable to download pdf blob url on Safari

Tags: pdf, safari, filereader

Currently using FileReader to open and view a PDF that works on Chrome. However, when the pdf is opened on Safari and you click the download button, nothing happens.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    $window.location.href = reader.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: This is happening with me as well. @Tyler Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash I haven't, I noticed that IE doesn't allow for blob urls over a certain length, so I switched to a server solution.

Comment: @TylerPflueger see my latest answer

Answer (score 15):

After having spent an entire day working on a similar issue, I understood where the problem was so I can now share my knowledge with you.

Basically, this kind of problems are generated when you render the `Blob` inside the already opened browser tab so your page url changes in something like:

`blob:http://localhost:8080/9bbeffe1-b0e8-485d-a8bd-3ae3ad9a0a51`

The wrong procedure for requiring a pdf would be something like this:

`var fileBlob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
window.location.hfref = fileBlob;`

Why doesn't this work?
Well, you can see the pdf rendered on the page so you might be fooled to thinking that your pdf is loaded fine. However, if you either try to refresh the page or download the pdf on your machine, it doesn't work.

WTH?
So, initially I was really thinking of some sort of black magic going around the browser, then I figured out the problem:
The file doesn't exist but its only cache stored inside the browser. So, when you generate the blob and you redirect your current tab to point to the generated blob url, you lose the cache.

Now everything makes sense right?

1. You request a file on the server
2. The browser stores the buffer inside the tab
3. You point your page url to read the buffer
4. You see the pdf but at the same time, you lose the buffer information

The only think you can do, is opening the Blob url in a new tab with:

`window.open(fileBlob, '_blank');`

Problem solved.

Comment: But this way if you have an adblock, it will silently close the tab that you open (you see it for a split second) with window.open ... Did you find a work around or even face this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the best solution I found so far. If you know of a better way, please share. Thanks for highlighting this scenario, I hope someone will benefit of your comment.

Comment: Check my new answer. Hope it helps anyone with the same issue, after all... nowadays adblock is frequently used

Comment: I am not able to pass blob object in window.open() method. Can you please check?

Answer (score 3):

After going through the same scenario as @andreasonny83 answer, plus having the headache issue of an adblock that closed the tab opened with `window.open` in a split second, I found a solution that worked for me. Not sure if it works in Safari since i do not have a mac to test it. Tried on Firefox and Chrome. I'm sure if it doesn't work on IE or Safari there's a workaround. What I did was using the *embed* html5 component providing as a src, an **URL.createObject(blob)** object. That way I was able to render/refresh and download the pdf.

```
  // pdfBlob is the pdf fetched from the API as a blob.
  pdf = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob)
```

Then you just embed that pdf into an `embed` tag like this:

```
<div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
    <embed src={pdf} type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%' />
</div>
```

The key was to use the html5 tag *embed*. It worked nicely. Of course you need to find a way to set the `embed` *src* attribute. I'm using react and redux so i use jsx, but you can use plain vanilla javascript or whatever you like.

Comment: I just tried this.  Looks great on chrome/firefox and iOS safari but i get a blank embed window in desktop safari.  Sad.  Still looking for a good solution.