Why is there a 40-second delay in calling the `URL.revokeObjectURL` method?
The source code FileSaver.js#L106
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href) }, 4E4) // 40s
setTimeout(function () { click(a) }, 0)

Why is there a 40-second delay in calling the URL.revokeObjectURL method? Why don't call it immediately after calling URL.createObjectURL(blob)?

Might be due to this https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41380177

What do you think happens in line 3 if it is revoked immediately?

@Davi Yeah, I know, some implementation will call click(a) immediately , then call URL.revokeObjectURL  after it. The question is not the asynchronous and synchronous code execution order. Just the delay in calling the URL.revokeObjectURL method

So you want to know why it is the number 40 instead of - say - 0?

@Davi Yes, why delay 40 seconds instead of 60 seconds or 0 seconds or immediately.Is there any limit? Otherwise, it can be any delay in seconds.

You need at least some delay before calling revokeObjectURL, because by calling it the browser schedules a GC that'll trash the object and therefor makes a click on the link pretty useless. Why the developer chose 40 is something you should ask the developer.

@Davi does it mean that all scheduled urls will be revoked at the same time if we call revokeObjectURL before GC runs?

@Konrad If that's a real question, please ask it as one. However: The browser marks the revoked resource that is pointed to by the URL to be collectable by the garbage collector. So when the next GC cycle runs, the formerly associated object is trashed. Since you cannot know when the next GC cycle is, it is not safe to assume that by immediately calling revokeObjectURL the resource is still there when the click code runs. I hope that I've been clearer this time.

Not sure if this is a dup, but it might be helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240551/how-can-i-revoke-an-object-url-only-after-its-downloaded

@danh Thanks, the answer explains there should be a delay, but does not explain how long should the delay be.

You cannot know what the delay should be beforehand, because it'd mean you do know how long it is going to take the user to download. Therefor, I guess that 40 was chosen as an arbitrary large number that most of the time seems to work. Again: Ask that question the developer or just accept that it is set to 40. It's impossible to give a valid answer here, except by the person that developed the code.

If the URL is immediately revoked, the resource will be unavailable when the next line of code (asynchronous event) runs. There would be a failure to download or a broken link to the image if the resource was not accessible.The best practice is to determine the appropriate delay. If you are able to get the file in less time, then use that delay

And how do you measure the time the file needed to download on the client's end before it has been downloaded?
