# chrome pdf viewer download html5 blob - network failed error

Tags: google-chrome, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

We are loading PDF as blob on chrome browser, that displays document using chrome pdf viewer plugin.

When we try to download pdf using icon provided on tool bar, network failed error is shown. Please see screenshot below[image]

Please help.

Comment: Found solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196495/chrome-pdf-viewer-cant-download-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome PDF viewer can't download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196495/chrome-pdf-viewer-cant-download-file)

Comment: This solution fixed my issue in my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/55705784/19594602

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669785/4190411